# Add a key to the current array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I get POST with multiple inputs.

```
<input name="options[]" type="text"/>
<input name="options[]" type="text"/>
<input name="options[]" type="text"/>
```

PHP:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($_POST['options'] as $option) { 

    $yok[] = array('sik'. $i++ => $option); 

}

$result = json_encode($yok);

// $result : ' [{"sik0":"op1"},{"sik1":"op2"},{"sik2":"op3"},{"sik3":"op4"}]  ';

My Goal:

// $result : ' {"sik0":"op1", "sik1":"op2", "sik2":"op3", "sik3":"op4"} ';
```

What do I need to order my goal? 
I've looked at many arrays, but unfortunately I didn't succeed.

Comment: So you want a single object with loads of properties instead of an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing this in one dimensional array and then encoding it as an object. Here is an example:

```
$i = 0;
$yok = [];
foreach ($_POST['options'] as $option) { 
    $yok['sik'.$i++] = $option;
}
echo json_encode($yok, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

This way you create a one dimensional intermediate array, for example:

```
[
    'sik0' => 5,
    'sik1' => 6
];
```

which then you force to be encoded into JSON object. The flag `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` is only needed if the array would be non-associative.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($_POST['options'] as $option) { 

     $yok["sik{$i}"] = $option;
     $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a little test with phpunit to give an answer and a little refactoring:

```
<?php

class AddKeyTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function setUp() : void
    {
        $this->sampleOptions = [];
        $this->sampleOptions[] = "op1";
        $this->sampleOptions[] = "op2";
        $this->sampleOptions[] = "op3";
        $this->sampleOptions[] = "op4";
    }

    public function testReachGoalWithSuccess()
    {
        $case = new AddKey();
        $result = $case->run($this->sampleOptions);

        $expect = '{"sik0":"op1","sik1":"op2","sik2":"op3","sik3":"op4"}';

        $this->assertEquals($expect, $result);
    }
}
```

Test is green with this class:

```
<?php

class AddKey
{
    private $yok = [];

    public function run(array $options) : string
    {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $this->yok['sik'. count($this->yok)] = $option;
        }

        return json_encode($this->yok);
    }
}
```

---

a class is not mandatory. So, ... here a function:

```
function reachGoal($options)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($options as $option) {
        $result['sik'. count($result)] = $option;
    }

    return json_encode($result);
}
```